# string to time over 24 hour in php

Tags: php, time, strtotime

There is a synatax errro  your variable name is $hour but in last you have used $hours.

```
$time1  = strtotime("02:40:00");
$time2 = strtotime("34:20:00");
$diff  = $time2 - $time1;

$hour   = floor($diff / (60 * 60));
$minute = $diff - $hour * (60 * 60);
//$final = $hours .":".floor( $minute / 60 );
$final = $hour .":".floor( $minute / 60 );

echo $final;
```

Comment: date time functions in PHP are for dealing with actual date-time. What you're doing is dealing with maths that resembles date-time. Please write a generic program to solve it using maths instead of using default PHP functions. You can create your own class/functions for doing the arithmetic that you require.

Comment: in what unversity you've found 34h hours format?

Comment: why you take $hours in `$final = $hours .":".floor( $minute / 60 );`

Comment: I have heard first time:- `34 hours 20 minutes`

Comment: If the php function can not solve this problem, I ask the solution to everything. How can I reduce the data as above I have typed?

Comment: @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi  it's not about php, it's about time is completley invalid, because there is nothing like 34 hours exist on the earth. No other language/code platform is going to solve this

Comment: Actually I have a total data usage hours, 34 hours it is the data that increases on the use of mill rollers. I asked for a solution how to reduce the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with a custom function like below:-

```
<?php

$actual_time = "34:20";

$time_to_reduce = "2:40";

function timeSubtactionFirstTime($actual_time ,$time_to_reduce){
   $actual_time_array = explode(":",$actual_time);
   $time_to_reduce = explode(":",$time_to_reduce);
   $final_result = [];
   if($actual_time_array[1] < $time_to_reduce[1]){
     $actual_time_array[0] = $actual_time_array[0]-1;
     $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[1]+60-$time_to_reduce[1];
   }else{
     $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[1]-$time_to_reduce[1];
   }
    $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[0]-$time_to_reduce[0];

    return implode(":", array_reverse($final_result));
}

echo timeSubtactionFirstTime($actual_time ,$time_to_reduce);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/920129

Note:- i din't consider seconds here. a bit mor logic is reuired for that

Answer (score 0):

Convert your time strings to DateInteval strings

```
$time1  = "02:40:00";
$time2  = "34:20:00";

list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $time1);
$time1 = new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$m}M{$s}S");
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $time2);
$time2 = new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$m}M{$s}S");

$T1 = new DateTime('midnight');
$T2 = clone $T1;
$T1->add($time1)->sub($time2);
$diff = $T2->diff($T1);

echo ($diff->invert ? '-' : '') . ($diff->d*24 + $diff->h) . ':' .$diff->i;
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/920157)

Comment: What do yuo not understand - how get `PT02H40M` from `02:00` ?

Comment: sorry I did not read the part you ordered to convert the string into the date interval.
Your help is very helpful, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had my own way of doing it:

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculate the number of hours and minutes between two times.
 * @param  string $start The start time
 * @param  string $end   The end time
 * @return string        The difference in hours and minutes
 */
function timeDiff( $start, $end )
{
    // Since the end time may be more than 23 hours ...
    $seg = (int) substr( $end, 0, 2 );

    // Add seconds to time2 ?
    $add = $seg > 23
        ? ( $seg - 23 ) * 3600
        : 0;

    // Subtract hours from time 2 if necessary
    if( $seg > 23 )
        $end = substr_replace( $end, '23', 0, 2 );

    // Compute the diff in seconds
    $time1 = strtotime($start);
    $time2 = strtotime($end) + $add;
    $diff  = $time2 - $time1;

    // How many hours and minutes were there ?
    $hour   = floor( $diff / (60 * 60) );
    $minute = $diff - $hour * (60 * 60);
    $minute = floor( $minute / 60 );

    // Pad the hours and minutes
    $hour = str_pad( $hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $minute = str_pad( $minute, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

    return $hour . ':' . $minute;
}

// Simple test
$start = "02:40:00";
$end   = "34:20:00";
echo timeDiff( $start, $end );
```

And if you also want to calculate seconds, then it is slightly modified:

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculate the number of hours, minutes, 
 *   and seconds between two times.
 * @param  string $start The start time
 * @param  string $end   The end time
 * @return string        The difference in hours:minutes:seconds
 */
function timeDiff( $start, $end )
{
    // Since the end time may be more than 23 hours ...
    $seg = (int) substr( $end, 0, 2 );

    // Add seconds to time2 ?
    $add = $seg > 23
        ? ( $seg - 23 ) * 3600
        : 0;

    // Subtract hours from time 2 if necessary
    if( $seg > 23 )
        $end = substr_replace( $end, '23', 0, 2 );

    // Compute the diff in seconds
    $time1 = strtotime($start);
    $time2 = strtotime($end) + $add;
    $diff  = $time2 - $time1;

    // How many hours and minutes were there ?
    $hour   = floor( $diff / (60 * 60) );
    $minute = $diff - $hour * (60 * 60);
    $minute = floor( $minute / 60 );
    $second = $diff - ( $hour * 60 * 60 ) - ( $minute * 60 );

    // Pad the hours, minutes, and seconds
    $hour = str_pad( $hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $minute = str_pad( $minute, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $second = str_pad( $second, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

    return $hour . ':' . $minute . ':' . $second;
}

// Simple test
$start = "02:40:00";
$end   = "34:20:45";
echo timeDiff( $start, $end );
```