# How to subtract time from array values using php?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, numbers, subtraction

I have this array.

```
$val = array(12:10, 4:16, 2:05);
```

I want to subtract `14:00` hrs from the `$val` array in the way that from every element that element do not become negative like this:

```
$val = array(0, 2:26, 2:05)
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far? Add your code attempt in the question

Comment: Also `2:05` needs to be `0:05` in the output array, isn't it?

Comment: Why is `12:10  - 14hrs = 0` and `4:16 - 14hrs = 2:26`? Please add a consistent required output example.

Comment: kindly help me to build the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = "14:00";
$val = array("12:10", "4:16", "2:05");

function timeSubtractionFirstTime($actual_time ,$time_to_reduce){
   $actual_time_array = explode(":",$actual_time);
   $time_to_reduce = explode(":",$time_to_reduce);
   $final_result = [];
   if($actual_time_array[1] < $time_to_reduce[1]){
     $actual_time_array[0] = $actual_time_array[0]-1;
     $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[1]+60-$time_to_reduce[1];
   }else{
     $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[1]-$time_to_reduce[1];
   }
    $final_result[] = $actual_time_array[0]-$time_to_reduce[0];

    return implode(":", array_reverse($final_result));
}

$timeToReduceLeft = $input;
foreach ($val as &$value) {
    $diff = timeSubtractionFirstTime($value, $timeToReduceLeft);
    if (strpos($diff, chr(45)) !== false){ //if $value < $timeToReduceLeft
        $timeToReduceLeft = timeSubtractionFirstTime($timeToReduceLeft, $value);
        $value = "00:00";
    }
    else { //if $value >= $timeToReduceLeft
        $value = timeSubtractionFirstTime($value, $timeToReduceLeft);
        $timeToReduceLeft = "00:00";
    }
    
    
    if ($timeToReduceLeft == "00:00"){
        break;
    }

}

echo implode(",", $val);
```

I get the function to extract time from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843311/string-to-time-over-24-hour-in-php) and implement the logic for your problem as follows:

We substract the time from input value until the input value become zero or entire array elements become zero (by forloop).

This solution also works with input or array elements value greater than "24:00".